# Making an effective footer in vaadin

Tags: interface, footer, vaadin

I'm new in `vaadin` and I need some help. I have a web application seems like windows desktop application and I want to make footer with some logos with links. `http://www.inovamer.com.tr/` like this one. can someone explain how can I make it ?

```
VerticalLayout footer = new VerticalLayout();

mainLayout.addComponent(footer);
mainLayout.setExpandRatio(content, 1);
```

I tried to make something like that but not really made what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mainlayout has to be full sized.

```
VerticalLayout vlMain = new VerticalLayout();
vlMain.setSizeFull();

vlMain.addComponent(content);
vlMain.setExpandRatio(content, 1.0f);

VerticalLayout footer = new VerticalLayout();
vlMain.addComponent(footer);
```